# HPQC (or MicroFocus ALM) - Errors when using Doc Generator on VDI

Tags: alm, microfocus

I work in a company that started using VDIs for certain SQAs. We have just noticed that in Microfocus ALM in the VDI only, when anyone tries to print a report through the Document Generator, an error occurs. See first screenshot. If you close this out, it freezes the browser and you have to close. When you try again, you'll get the second error below. In researching these, it seems the first could be caused by a Word incompatibility, which we have checked and ruled out. The second can be caused by files in the path of the TD_80 folder, which we have tried to remove as suggested, but the error persists.

Does anyone know what else might cause this error on the VDIs only?

[Details from first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4biR.png)

[Details from second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vVi6.png)

Answer (score 1):

After submitting a ticket to Micro Focus, they said Report Generator is no longer supported. They pointed us to their documentation on creating reports in the Analysis View module under the Dashboard. This seems to work similarly, but the filtering is a little bit different.